# LiFePo4 Battery's BMS is clipping when my relay switch kicks-in

Tags: motor, switches, relay, bms, lifepo4

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQcHXR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

My trolling motor had no "kill-switch" that would turn the motor off should I get dumped into the water.  So I purchased a standard "kill-switch" which is a normally open circuit when the "kill-key" is clipped into place.  I then wired it as follows:  (1) from battery negative terminal to fuse.  (2) from fuse to post #30 on the 12 volt 60/80amp relay.  (3) from fuse to "kill-switch).  (4) from "kill switch" to post #85 on the relay.  (4) from positive terminal of the battery to another fuse on the positive side.  (5) from fuse on the positive side to post 86 of the relay.  (6) from post 87a of the relay to the trolling motor.  (7) post 87 of the relay is currently not used, but the concept is to connect 87 to some strobe lights and a siren on the battery box so that should I go overboard, not only would the motor quit, but the coil would charge thus switching over to 87 output and sound the warning to anyone nearby.
AFTER wiring it all up, all seemed good.  There is battery meter on the box that was lit letting me know.  I yanked out the key to test it, and the meter went out.  Made sense as it was previously wired (when first posted, it was being cut off when relay tripped).  I put the key back in to open the circuit, discharge the coil, switching back to post 87a -- BUT NADA.  I put a meter on the battery, and it registered just under 5 volts.  I put the battery on the charger and it immediately came back to life.  I checked on the wiring and added more insulation between the relay posts to no avail.  It seems that the coil was tripping the BMS.  I believed I needed to add a resistor but was not sure the size nor where in the wiring set-up I should place the resistor.  [subsequently resolved-when meter re-wired to always connect regardless of 87 or 87a output -- that small amount of resistance is all it took: see schematic after resolution]-- I'm a hobbyist and not so technically knowledgeable.
BTW -- someone could make some money manufacturing a proper battery box with a built in kill switch and over-board alarm system.  I could see many who use trolling motors gobbling them up.

Comment: Welcome! Please post a schematic or block diagram of 1-7.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I would rather swap he BMS with one that has on/off switch or do some reverse engineer of BMS, let's say over-temperature, cell under-voltage,... to power off the load.

Comment: Thanks Winny!  I created a schematic (to the best of my graphic ability).  In doing so, I realized that I had the ground to the voltimeter wired so that it would disconnect when the coil charged and the relay switch went over to the n.o. side.  I wondered:  Could it be that such a slight resistance from the voltimeter could make a difference?  So, I repositioned the negative wire of the voltimeter so that it would stay closed even after the relay switched over.  Voila!  That's all it took!  I am surprised that so little resistance could make a difference.  Posting schematic once I learn how.

Comment: A good start, but very hard to read. If you click on edit and the schematic symbol, you can draw a schematic from there. Try to draw all inputs to the left and output/end use on the right. Positive voltages on up, ground on bottom.

Comment: Thanks again Winny.  I'll try that because I see myself needing this site again.

Comment: Winny, or others.  Please comment on the schematic as to any potential downfalls, etc.

Comment: What happened to my real schematic?  I left with the handwritten one deleted and proper one saved and uploaded.